# does facebook know your IP address and hence your location?

Tags: facebook, ip, router, vpn

When creating a facebook account on a laptop device on WiFi via a standard router, does facebook know your IP address and hence your location?

So if you create an account in e.g. a flat in Berlin, Germany, on a standard wireless/wifi connection via a standard router and internet provider, will facebook know your IP address when you sign up and store it so it knows Fred Blogs created his account in Berlin , Germany so he must be from there.

Does anybody know if Facebook keeps this info and releases it to authorities if they ask for it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question fit for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they know your location. This is because the ip address you get is after the router and will be an internal network ip inside the default range 192.168. or for private networks it will be something in 10.10.

The ip address that will be visible by the site you visit or app you use or whatever you access on the net will be the incomming, mostly fixed, ip provided by your ISP.

So by using GeoIP it is rather close position.

But as always you can use a VPN or bounce over some Proxies and even clone your mac address and try to hide your real position for a while.

Normally, this is European law but not folowed up real hard except in The Netherlands, there should be a setting you can use to disable tracking and analytics and even the usage of cookies.